# Debugger get stuck at start of function

Tags: c++, constructor

Consider the following code: 
When run with visual studio, the debugger gets stuck upon entering the test_create function in the testLevel_0 class. I believe this has something to do with the initialization of the Disk struct by I can't find the problem. For some reason, Disk's constructor is never called. If a Disk is declared in any other function, similar problems arise.

```
using namespace std; 

typedef bitset<1600> DATtype;
bool charToBool(char ch)
{
    return ch != '0';
}


string getDateNow()
{
    char temp[10];
    int a;
    string ret;
    time_t now;
    struct tm *current;
    now = time(0);
    current = localtime(&now);
    ret = ((current->tm_mday < 10)? '0'+current->tm_mday:current->tm_mday);
    ret += ":" ;
    ret += ((current->tm_mon < 10)? '0'+current->tm_mon:current->tm_mon);
    ret += ":";
    ret += _itoa(current->tm_year+1900,temp,10);
    return ret;
}

struct VHD
{

    char diskName[12]; // disk name
    char diskOwner[12]; // disk owner name
    char probDate[10]; // creation date
    unsigned int clusQty; // cluster total on disk
    unsigned int dataClusQty; // number of allocational units for data 
    unsigned int addrDAT; // DAT sector address
    unsigned int addrRootDir; // root cluster address
    unsigned int addrDATcpy; // DAT copy sector address
    unsigned int addrRootDirCpy; // root copy cluster address
    unsigned int addrDataStart; // address of first cluster meant for data
    char formatDate[10]; // format date
    bool isFormatted; // is formatted
    char emptyArea[947]; // saved memory for future use

    VHD()
    {
        strcpy(diskName,"name");
        strcpy(diskOwner,"owner");
        strcpy(probDate,"00/00/000");
        clusQty = dataClusQty = addrDAT = addrRootDir = addrDATcpy = addrRootDirCpy = addrDataStart = 0;
        strcpy(formatDate,"00/00/0000");
        isFormatted = false;
        strcpy(emptyArea,"000000000");
    }


    VHD(VHD& copy)
    {
        strcpy(diskName , copy.diskName);
        strcpy(diskOwner , copy.diskOwner);
        strcpy(probDate , copy.probDate);
        clusQty = copy.clusQty;
        dataClusQty = copy.dataClusQty;
        addrDAT = copy.addrDAT;
        addrRootDir = copy.addrRootDir;
        addrDATcpy = copy.addrDATcpy;
        addrRootDirCpy = copy.addrRootDirCpy;
        addrDataStart = copy.addrDataStart;
        strcpy(formatDate , copy.formatDate);
        isFormatted = copy.isFormatted;
        strcpy(emptyArea , copy.emptyArea);
    }

    const const char * toData()
    {
        string ret = diskName;
        ret += diskOwner;
        ret += probDate;
        ret += (char *)clusQty;
        ret += (char *)dataClusQty;
        ret += (char *)addrDAT;
        ret += (char *)addrRootDir;
        ret += (char *)addrDATcpy;
        ret += (char *)addrRootDirCpy;
        ret += (char *)addrDataStart;
        ret += formatDate;
        ret += (char) isFormatted;
        ret += emptyArea;
        return ret.c_str();
    }
};

struct DAT  
{

    unsigned int sectrNr;
    DATtype dat;
    char emptyArea[816];

    DAT()
    {
        sectrNr = 0;
        strcpy(emptyArea,"0000000000000");
    }

    const char * toData()
    {
        string ret = dat.to_string();
        ret += emptyArea;
        return ret.c_str();
    }
};

struct dirEntry
{
    char fileName [12]; // name of file
    char fileOwner[12]; // owner of file
    unsigned int fileAddr; // address of first sector of file
    char crDate[10]; // date of file creation
    unsigned int fileSize; // size of file, number of sectors
    unsigned int eofRecNr; // "end of file" location
    unsigned int maxRecSize; // max record size
    unsigned int actualRecSize; // actual record size
    char recFormat[2]; // record format: 'F','V' - data; 'D' - sub-directory
    unsigned int keyOffset; // offset of key within record
    unsigned int keySize; // size of key
    char keyType[2]; // type of key: 'I' - int, 'F' - float, 'D' - double, 'C' - char/string
    unsigned char entryStatus;// status of file entry: 0 - entry is empty, 1 - entry is active, 2 - entry is not active 

    dirEntry()
    {
        strcpy(fileName,"name");
        strcpy(fileOwner,"owner");
        strcpy(crDate,"00/00/0000");
        fileAddr = fileSize = eofRecNr = maxRecSize = actualRecSize = keyOffset = keySize = 0;
        strcpy(recFormat,"00");
        strcpy(keyType,"00");
        entryStatus = '0';
    }

    const char * toData()
    {
        string ret = fileName;
        ret += fileOwner;
        ret += (char *)fileAddr;
        ret += crDate;
        ret += (char *)fileSize;
        ret += (char *)eofRecNr;
        ret += (char *)maxRecSize;
        ret += (char *)actualRecSize;
        ret += recFormat;
        ret += (char *)keyOffset;
        ret += (char *)keySize;
        ret += keyType;
        ret += entryStatus;
        return ret.c_str();
    }
};

struct rootDirSec
{
    unsigned int sectorNr;
    dirEntry rootdir[14];
    char emptyArea[12];

    rootDirSec()
    {
        sectorNr = 0;
        strcpy(emptyArea,"00000");
    }

    const char * toData()
    {
        string ret;
        for(int i=0;i<18;i++)
            ret += rootdir[i].toData();
        return ret.c_str();
    }
};

struct rootDirectory
{
    rootDirSec rootDirs[2];

    const char * toData()
    {
        string ret;
        for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
            ret += rootDirs[i].toData();
        return ret.c_str();
    }

};

struct fileHeader
{
    unsigned int sectorNr; // sector number
    dirEntry fileDesc; // file descriptor
    DATtype fat; // file access table
    char emptyArea[744]; 

    fileHeader()
    {
        sectorNr = 0;
        strcpy(emptyArea,"0000000");
    }

    const char * toData()
    {
        string ret = fileDesc.toData();
        ret += fat.to_string();
        ret += emptyArea;
        return ret.c_str();
    }
};

struct sector
{
    unsigned int sectorNr; // sector number
    char rawData[1020]; // data

    sector()
    {
        sectorNr = 0;
        strcpy(rawData,"000000000");
    }

    const char * toData()
    {
        return rawData;
    }
};

struct cluster
{
    sector sectors[2];

    const char * toData()
    {
        string ret = sectors[0].toData();
        ret += sectors[1].toData();
        return ret.c_str();
    }
};

struct Disk
{
    cluster clusters[1600];

    friend class TestLevel_0;
    VHD vhd;// cluster 0 sector 0
    DAT dat;// cluster 0 sector 1

    //rootDirectory rootDir; // clusters 1 - 1599
    bool mounted; // if disk is mounted - true
    fstream dskfl;
    unsigned int currDiskSectorNr; // indexer

    Disk()
    {
        mounted = false; // all other fields are automatically initialized when Disk is declared
    }
    Disk(string & name, string & owner, char code, unsigned int a = 0)
    {
    mounted = false;
    switch(code)
    {
        case 'c':
            createdisk(name,owner);
        case 'm':
            mountdisk(name);
            break;
    }


}
    ~Disk()
    {
        unmountdisk();
    }

    void strToVHD(string str)
    {
        string temp[10];
        int pos = 0;
        if(str.length() != 1)
            return;
        strcpy(vhd.diskName,str.substr(pos,12).c_str()); pos +=12;
        strcpy(vhd.diskOwner,str.substr(pos,12).c_str()); pos += 12;
        strcpy(vhd.probDate,str.substr(pos,10).c_str()); pos += 10;
        vhd.clusQty = atoi(str.substr(pos,sizeof(int)).c_str()); pos += sizeof(int);
        vhd.dataClusQty = atoi(str.substr(pos,sizeof(int)).c_str()); pos += sizeof(int);
        vhd.addrDAT = atoi(str.substr(pos,sizeof(int)).c_str()); pos += sizeof(int);
        vhd.addrRootDir = atoi(str.substr(pos,sizeof(int)).c_str()); pos += sizeof(int);
        vhd.addrDATcpy = atoi(str.substr(pos,sizeof(int)).c_str()); pos += sizeof(int);
        vhd.addrRootDirCpy = atoi(str.substr(pos,sizeof(int)).c_str()); pos += sizeof(int);
        vhd.addrDataStart = atoi(str.substr(pos,sizeof(int)).c_str()); pos += sizeof(int);
        strcpy(vhd.formatDate,str.substr(pos,10).c_str()); pos += 10;
        vhd.isFormatted = charToBool(str.at(pos++));
        strcpy(vhd.emptyArea,str.substr(pos,947).c_str()); 
    }
    string VHDTostr()
    {
        char temp[10];
        string str = vhd.diskName;
        str += vhd.diskOwner;
        str += vhd.probDate;
        str += _itoa(vhd.clusQty,temp,10);
        str += _itoa(vhd.dataClusQty,temp,10);
        str += _itoa(vhd.addrDAT,temp,10);
        str += _itoa(vhd.addrRootDir,temp,10);
        str += _itoa(vhd.addrDATcpy,temp,10);
        str += _itoa(vhd.addrRootDirCpy,temp,10);
        str += _itoa(vhd.addrDataStart,temp,10);
        str += vhd.formatDate;
        str += (vhd.isFormatted?'1':'0');
        str += vhd.emptyArea;
        return str;
    }
    void createdisk(string & name, string & owner)
    {
        dskfl.open(name,ios::binary);
        for(int i=0,k=0,j=0;i<2;i++,k=1)
            for(;j<1600;j++,k+=2)
                clusters[j].sectors[i].sectorNr = k;
        strcpy(vhd.diskName,name.c_str());
        strcpy(vhd.diskOwner,owner.c_str());
        time_t now = time(0);
        strcpy(vhd.formatDate,getDateNow().c_str());
        vhd.clusQty = 1600;
        vhd.dataClusQty = 1596;
        vhd.addrDAT = 1;
        vhd.addrRootDir = 1; 
        vhd.addrDataStart = 2;
        vhd.addrDATcpy = 1599;
        vhd.addrRootDirCpy = 800;
        vhd.isFormatted = false;
        strcpy(clusters[0].sectors[0].rawData,vhd.toData());

        char temp[10];
        for(int i=0,j;i<1600;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<2;j++)
            {
                dskfl.write(_itoa(clusters[i].sectors[j].sectorNr,temp,10),sizeof(int));
                dskfl.write(clusters[i].sectors[j].rawData,sizeof(char[1020]));
            }
        }
    }
    void mountdisk(string & file)
    {
        char * str = new char;
        dskfl.open(file ,ios::binary);
        dskfl.get(str,sizeof(int));
        clusters[0].sectors[0].sectorNr = (int)str;
        dskfl.get(str,sizeof(char[1020]));
        strcpy(clusters[0].sectors[0].rawData,str);
        strToVHD(str);
        mounted = true;
    }
    void unmountdisk()
    {
        string str = VHDTostr();
        strcpy(clusters[0].sectors[0].rawData , str.c_str());
        dskfl.close();
        mounted = false;
    }
    void recreatedisk(string & name)
    {
        dskfl.open(name , ios::binary);
        if(!dskfl.is_open() || mounted)
            return;

        VHD newVhd;
        strcpy(newVhd.diskName,name.c_str());
        strcpy(newVhd.diskOwner,vhd.diskOwner);
        time_t now = time(0);
        strcpy(newVhd.formatDate,getDateNow().c_str());
        newVhd.clusQty = 1600;
        newVhd.addrDAT = 1;
        newVhd.addrRootDir = 2; 
        newVhd.isFormatted = false;
        vhd = newVhd;
        strcpy(clusters[0].sectors[0].rawData,vhd.toData());

        char temp[10];
        for(int i=0,j;i<1600;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<2;j++)
            {
                dskfl.write(_itoa(clusters[i].sectors[j].sectorNr,temp,10),sizeof(int));
                dskfl.write(clusters[i].sectors[j].rawData,sizeof(char[1020]));
            }
        }
    }
    fstream * getdskfl()
    {
        if(dskfl.is_open())
            return &dskfl;
        return  0x0;
    }
    void seekToSector(unsigned int index)
    {
        if(index <= 0 || index >= 1600)
            throw;
        currDiskSectorNr = index;
    }
    void writeSector(unsigned int index, sector * sec)
    {
        try
        {
            seekToSector(index);
        }
        catch(exception ex)
        {
            throw "Error index input";
        }
        writeSector(sec);
        currDiskSectorNr+=2;
    }
    void writeSector(sector * sec)
    {
        for(int i=0,j,k;i<1600;i++)
            for(j=0;j<2;j++,k++)
                if(k == currDiskSectorNr)
                    strcpy(clusters[i].sectors[j].rawData , sec->rawData);
        currDiskSectorNr--;
    }
    void readSector(int index, sector * sec)
    {
        try
        {
            seekToSector(index);
        }
        catch(exception ex)
        {
            throw "Error index input";
        }
        readSector(sec);
        currDiskSectorNr+=2;
    }
    void readSector(sector * sec)
    {
        for(int i=0,j,k;i<1600;i++)
            for(j=0;j<2;j++,k++)
                if(k == currDiskSectorNr)
                    strcpy(sec->rawData , clusters[i].sectors[j].rawData );
        currDiskSectorNr--;
    }
};


class TestLevel_0
{
    static void printStructSize()
    {
        cout <<"printing struct size:\n";
        cout << "Size of sector -> " << sizeof(sector);
        cout << "\nSize of volumeHeader -> " << sizeof(VHD);
        cout << "\nSize of DAT -> " << sizeof(DAT);
        cout << "\nSize of dirEntry -> " << sizeof(dirEntry);
        cout << "\nSize of fileHeader -> " << sizeof(fileHeader);
        cout << "\nSize of rootDir -> " << sizeof(rootDirectory) << endl;
    }

    static void printDiskInfo(Disk & d)
    {
        VHD * vh = &d.vhd;
        cout << "Disk name: " << vh->diskName;
        cout << "\nOwner name: " << vh->diskOwner;
        cout << "\nProdDate: " << vh->probDate;
        cout << "\nformatDate: " << vh->formatDate;
        cout << "\nisFormated: " << vh->isFormatted;
        cout << "\naddrDataStart: " << vh->addrDataStart;

        cout << "\nclusQty: " << vh->clusQty;
        cout << "\ndataClusQty: " << vh->dataClusQty;

        cout << "\naddrDAT: " << vh->addrDAT;
        cout << "\naddrDATcpy: " << vh->addrDATcpy;
        cout << "\naddrRootDir: " << vh->addrRootDir;
        cout << "\naddrRootDirCpy: " << vh->addrRootDirCpy << endl;
    }

    static void test_create(string& diskName, string& ownerName)
    {//GET STUCK HERE
        Disk d;
        cout << "Pre created disk: \n";
        printDiskInfo(d);
        d.createdisk(diskName,ownerName);
        cout << "Post created disk: \n";
        printDiskInfo(d);
    }

    static void test_mount(string diskName)
    {
        Disk d;
        cout << "Pre mounted disk: \n";
        printDiskInfo(d);
        d.mountdisk(diskName);
        cout << "Post mounted disk: \n";
        printDiskInfo(d);
    }

    static void test_rwSector(string diskName)
    {
        Disk d;
        sector s;
        d.mountdisk(diskName);
        cout << "read sectr: \n";
        d.readSector(8,&s);
        strcpy(s.rawData,"this is write temp secctor");
        d.readSector(8,&s);
        d.unmountdisk();
    }

public:
    static void test_0()
    {
        try
        {
            string name = "disk 1";
            string owner = "Josh & Tzuriel";
            printStructSize();
            test_create(name,owner);
            test_mount(name);

        }
        catch(exception ex)
        {
            cout << ex.what() << endl;
        }
    }



void main()
{
    TestLevel_0::test_0();
    char a;
    cin >> a;

}
```

Comment: How do you mean by "stuck"?? The `Disk` object's default CTOR will get called on the first line of `test_create`.

Comment: Do you have a breakpoint there?

Comment: What is sizeof(Disk) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The size of sector is 1kb.
You have 2 sectors in a cluster and 1600 clustors in a disk, and you're trying to allocate all of this on the stack.

Try using the heap